# check palindrome in a SINGLY link list

Tags: c, list, data-structures, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Single Linked List is Palindrome or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966068/single-linked-list-is-palindrome-or-not)

Suppose i have a link list having a char item,i need to find if the characters in that link list is a palindrome or not. I know link list not at all a suitable structure for this, but then if we have one what to do?

eg `a-b-c-b-a`

a doubly link list is easy,we can start of with the head and tail

```
ptrh=head ptrt=tail
if(ptrh->item==ptrt->item)
```

and

```
ptrh->ptrh->frwdlink
ptrt->ptrt->bcklink
```

But what if we have a single linked list? How to implement it then?

Comment: you can start by editing your question to remove all caps. you don't need shout here, you see...people can read. If you want to highlight something, use bold faces or stuff like that.

Comment: @Aftnix WHAT? WHAT DID YOU SAY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing the size of the list you can tell what the middle is. Then as you go through you just cache all the chars up to the middle and make sure they appear in reverse order after the middle.

Answer (score 3):

can you create temporary arrays?  Put all items in the linked list into an array, then compare index n with index (length - n).

```
var ptr = head; var array = [];

while (ptr != null)
{
  array.push(ptr.item);
  ptr = ptr.next;
}

for (var i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++)
{
  if (array[i] != array[array.length - i])
    return (false);
}

return (true);
```

Comment: ...and don't forget to take into account arrays with an odd length.

Answer (score 2):

you could build a list with the inverse order of nodes while going through the list for the first time.

and then compare the first n/2+1 nodes of the original and the inversed lists